# How to use Selenium with Digest Authentication?

Tags: selenium, digest-authentication

I am looking for a good way to use Selenium with Digest Authentication (for a flex UI though I don't think that makes a difference if I can't do authentication).  I'd like to avoid platform-dependencies such as using AutoIT to drive browser pop-ups (since cross-platform testing is a motivator for going to Selenium), though if there's a good cross-platform library for doing such things that would work fine.

I'm thinking maybe there is a way to use a separate http client to create a session and then pass the session credentials off to the browser, but I'm not sure how to inject the session ID into the browser requests.  That's just an idea I had, not sure how feasible it is.

Comment: If you have full control of the server under test you might also want to just disable the authentication and test without.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an HTTP proxy, such as [AuthProxy](https://github.com/cayblood/authproxy) by [@CarlYoungblood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281199/carl-youngblood).

It's an HTTP proxy server written in Ruby which was developed specifically for testing a server that required basic authentication with Selenium, but it should also work on a server with digest authentication.

Comment: I don't think a proxy server is a feasible answer for testing  a flex UI since there are REST calls directed straight to the server from the flex client, which would bypass any proxy (i.e. not explicitly performed by the browser).

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained, you cannot automate a Flex UI from Selenium, as it doesn't handle Flash for testing (you can embed the flash plugin in your browser, but Selenium won't be able to test against flash component...) 
Even if you can authenticate, you won't be able to test anything, so, you should try something else, like [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/)

Comment: @shamp00 My bad, i assumed it was for non intrusive-testing

Comment: @shamp00 My plan is to use the selenium flex plugin (and we've been able to construct some tests if we use manual authentication), but you'll note that I didn't tag this question with flex because my issue is not related to flex but to the digest authentication.